# adding header info to jQuery.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, header

I have the following code:

```
jQuery.post(encodeURI(ajaxurl + '?action=form_submission'), 
{ 'propertyID[]': propArray, submit: 'Export Gallery', NG_nonce: '<?php print    $this->nonce; ?>' },
function (result) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
   if (typeof(obj['error']) == 'undefined') {
      if (typeof(obj['url']) != 'undefined') {
         window.location.href = obj['url'];
         var confirmBox = confirm('The gallery has been exported.');
      } else {
         alert('Error');
      }
   } else {
      alert(obj['error']);
   }
   if (redirect == 1)   {
        window.location.href = '/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id='+propertyID+'&type=image&tab=<?php print $_REQUEST['tab']; ?>';
   } else {
        jQuery(element).html(oldHtml);
   }
});
```

This works perfectly, it creates a zipped folder that is then downloaded to the users machine. What I need to do is add header information so the user is given the 'save as' dialog box. I have tried several different things (trying to use request.setRequestHeader, including header information in the data portion) but I am having no luck. Can someone please send me in the correct direction on this? Thanks.

Or is there a way to add the header information right before

```
window.location.href = obj['url']
```

I need to figure this out, Thanks again for any help.

Comment: I have found when using jQuery.ajax you can add header key:value pairs, can you do the same type of things when using jQuery.post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "save as" dialog is up to the browser. Different browsers will handle file downloads differently.

Comment: I know in php you can use something like this:                      header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); to make it force the page to show the 'save as' dialog, I am trying to figure out how to add the header information in the jquery.post call

Comment: The jQuery post call is the request to the server. This php header you mentioned is the response from the server. You cannot force a header for the response from the server via jQuery.post, I don't think.